# google map API 3 loads map in top left corner, resize not working

Tags: google-maps, maps

I use google maps to load a map with latLng params.
That mostly works fine, but sometimes (like at the moment), the map is centered in the top left corner.
I tried the trick with
`google.maps.event.trigger(gomap, 'resize');`

but that didn't do, so I did what I found somewhere else and wrapped it in a listener that waits for the map to be idle :

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gomap, 'resize');
});
```

But that doesn't work either. I am not sure where I would have to put these, so my current code looks as follow (simplified)

```
var gomap;

function initialize(types,callback,lat,long,address) {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
  gomap = map;
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(['geocode'],'onAddressUpdate',lat,long,address));
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gomap, 'resize');
});
```

(The gomap = map is there because there's a couple of other instances that use var map, so I just assign map's value to the global gomap).

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you show complete code with styling information?

Comment: I will do so later, my boss has me doing something completely else. I put what I have on a JS fiddle, but it's awkward as there, it seems to work. It doesn't set the marker but the map centers correctly.

There's not a whole lot of styling for the map itself..
But yeah, I have it here : http://jsfiddle.net/UACMN/1/

Comment: There is no element with id `inputPlaceAddress`. Is it also hidden?

Comment: What is `window[callback](place);` where `callback` is `onAddressUpdate`?

Comment: If I update the [fiddle with an element with that id](http://jsfiddle.net/UACMN/2/), the map on the fiddle is centered on the marker.

Comment: I also got that result. I don't understand why are there two global variables for map: `gomap` and `map`. And there is another local `map` in another file.

Comment: Anto, I added the fields. And yes, I get that result as well, but it's not happening on the original page. 
I will set it up to be accessible to the public later, it's a.. thing. 
The thing with the two map variables... map is not a global (or at least shouldn't be). Because.. I don't even know. I took this entire thing over, but the varname map is used in various functions and places and I can't use it as global because if I do, it will get overwritten. Hence the gomap. That is just a dirty fix I guess, but it allowed me to use the resize function.

Comment: `map` is local in `gmInitialize()` function. Then you have `map` in `initialize()` function, which is global because there is no `var` in front of it.

Comment: Ah. That is because I first made it global to try and then forgot to readd "var". Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Thanks Anto, I found it because you asked me to show you the entire site. Was trying to figure out how to make the site accessible to the public and stumbled upon the solution (I'll post it as an answer in a second).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map is initially hidden and is shown when a certain button is clicked, and I noticed the issue did not occur when the map is shown on load.

So I changed the JavaScript to trigger a resize and recenter the map after the div is faded in :

```
$('#'+name).fadeIn(300,function(){
   google.maps.event.trigger(gomap, 'resize');
   map.setCenter(gopoint);
});
```

That fixed it for me.